# C# parse List<List<List<String>>> TO List<List<List<Int>>>

Tags: c#

can somebody please help me about this problem.

```
private int[] strategija1 (DataTable dtexcel)
{   
    List<List<List<String>>> dt_matrix = convert_list_3d_arrayList(dtexcel, dtexcel.Rows.Count, (dtexcel.Columns.Count) - 1); 

    make_me_a_travel_matrix(dt_matrix);
    return null;
}

public Array make_me_a_travel_matrix(List<List<List<int>>> list_matrica)
{
    int[,,,] Put = new int[20, 20, 20, 20];
    int i = 1;
    int pol = i;
    int j = 0;
    int Poc1=0, Poc2=0, Poc3=0;
    int x = 1, y = 1, k = 1;
    int odr = 0;
    korakB(ref  i, ref Put, ref  pol, ref j, ref x, ref y, ref k, ref odr, ref list_matrica, ref Poc1, ref Poc2, ref Poc3);
    for (int a = 0; a < Put.GetLength(0); a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < Put.GetLength(1); b++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Put[pol, odr, a, b]);
        }
    }
    return Put;
 }
```

I am receiving error on "dt_matrix" inside  "make_me_a_travel_matrix(dt_matrix);"

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>>'
> to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>>'  WindowsFormsApp1    ...\WinFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs  262 Active
```

Is there way to parse `List<List<List<String>>>   to    List<List<List<Int>>>?`

Comment: Your error says it can't convert a 'list of a list of a list' to a 'list of a list' (ie different depths).. It doesn't look like it's having problems with string to int conversion...

Comment: What is your `/* SOME CODE */`? Please edit your post to include that code, we're going to need that in order to help you.

Comment: added "some code", and changed error to display as code

Comment: You can use the [`Convert<T>`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_CoreLibraries_ObjectExtensions_Convert__1.htm) extension from [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries) library (disclaimer: written by me). See an [online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zKYILZ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a problem like this it is sometimes much easier when you break it down into subproblems.

First write a method to convert a single element:

```
public static int ConvertElement(string input) => int.Parse(input);
```

Then write a method to convert a list, using the first method to convert each element:

```
public static List<int> ConvertList(List<string> input) => input.Select(ConvertElement).ToList();
```

Then write a method to convert a list of lists, using the second method to convert each list.

```
public static List<List<int>> ConvertListList(List<List<string>> input) => input.Select(ConvertList).ToList();
```

Now your solution is easy:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var input = new List<List<string>>();
    List<List<int>> output = ConvertListList(input);
}
```

But if you prefer you can do it one method:

```
public static List<List<int>> ConvertListOfLists(List<List<string>> input)
{
    return input.Select
    (
        x => x.Select(int.Parse).ToList() 
    )
   .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have a question, in your code you used only   List<List<int>>    but in my situation  is  List<List<List<<int>>>...so i asume that your code wont work in my case

Comment: I think you should be able to take this example one step further to handle a ListListList. Just write one more method.

Comment: Ok, i was making small mistake, it is working (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want I think:

```
var newList = dt_matrix.Select(l => l.Select(l2 => l2.Select(int.Parse)));
```

This code will only work if you're sure every string you have can indeed be parsed into an int. This code will throw an exception if it encounter a string that cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

use a combination of Linq and Int.Parse like:

```
var string_list = new List<string>(){ "1","2","3" };
var int_list = string_list.Select( x => Int32.Parse( x ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`LINQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/write-linq-queries) or a simple set of [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-for-statement) loops. When it comes to parsing, there are several options. One is to use the [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-6.0) method which will convert the string to a number if it can. If it cannot, it will throw an exception. If you want to check whether a number can be parsed, you can use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) method as an alternative.

## Examples

##### Using `LINQ`

```
List<List<List<int>>> Parse(List<List<List<string?>>> input)
{
    return input.Select(a => a.Select(b => b.Select(int.Parse).ToList()).ToList()).ToList();
}
```

##### Using a set of `for` loops

```
List<List<List<int>>> Parse(List<List<List<string?>>> input)
{
    var numbers = new List<List<List<int>>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        numbers.Add(new List<List<int>>());
        for (int j = 0; j < input[i].Count; j++)
        {
            numbers[i].Add(new List<int>());
            for (int z = 0; z < input[i][j].Count; z++)
            {
                var newValue = int.Parse(input[i][j][z]);
                numbers[i][j].Add(newValue);
            }
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

##### Usage

```
var result = Parse(yourStringCollection);
```